# DO NOT send notifications when share a file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I made a code that copy and paste files for a folder to other, and that files are shared with other people, people that can edit o view the files.

I need when the copy and the permissions are copied to the new file, this DON'T sent the email notificactions to editors and viewers.

The first code that U used was this:

```
  var PeopleToEdit = file.getEditors();
  var PeopleToView = file.getViewers();
      for (var i=0 ; i < PeopleToEdit.length; i++){
      newFile.addEditor(PeopleToEdit[i]);}
      for (var i=0 ; i < PeopleToView.length; i++){
      newFile.addViewer(PeopleToView[i]);}
```

But then, for the email thing I was trying with this:

```
function addEditors(file1, file2){
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(file1);
var PeopleToEdit = file.getEditors();
for (var i=0 ; i < PeopleToEdit.length; i++){
       
 Drive.Permissions.insert(
  {
   'role': 'writer',
   'type': 'user',
   'value': PeopleToEdit[i].getEmail()
  },
  file2,
  {
   'sendNotificationEmails': 'true'
  });
```

In my local drive works, but when I used it in the shared drive, show this error, I don't have any idea what can be.

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: File not found: 1-qsWWwWZI2f0phJW4AO_LLP5fLn2Ica_MhkUClM-s-E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two things

1. When you create a Drive permission for a file on a shared drive, you need to set the parameter `supportsAllDrives` to `true`
2. If you do NOT want to send notifications, you need to set `sendNotificationEmails` to `false`

**Sample request:**

```js
Drive.Permissions.insert(
  {
   'role': 'writer',
   'type': 'user',
   'value': PeopleToEdit[i].getEmail()
  },
  file2,
  {
   'supportsAllDrives': true, 
   'sendNotificationEmails': false
  });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. The error isn't show it again, it works, but now is sharing only with the "members", the "guests" in the files that I'm copying don't appear in the new files. but thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi ! What do you mean by ```guests```? People which are not members of the shared Drive but had access to the file you are inserting the permissions? Is this file copy allocated in a shared Drive?

Comment: Hi again,
Yes, the files are in a shared Drive, but this files are shared individually with different people.
For example we're 16 people in the shared Drive, and this contain 6 files. Those 6 files are shared with the 16 people (members), and the file number 1 is shared at the same time with the members (16 people), and 4 people more (guests), and the file number 2 is share with the "members" and others different 7 people (guests).
When it runs, is sharing only with the members (16), I need that the files will share with the guests too. 
I don't know if I explain myself well, thanks a lot

Comment: In ```PeopleToEdit[i].getEmail()``` do you have all your desired users (i.e the ones in the shared Drive plus the ```guests```? When you log ```PeopleToEdit``` does this array contain all your desired users?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to perform the same request for `PeopleToView` in addition to `PeopleToEdit`?

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to run this. `GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.insert failed with error: Required` Any idea what that means and how to fix?

Comment: I see. I was not using FileID. Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024...

The accepted answer works, but you must choose **Drive API v2** in the Services tab in Apps Script.

**It won't work** with **v3**. Even if you make the minor adjustments, for instance, changing the method to `create` instead of `insert`, don't waste your time with v3.